# Using the drop.test function

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

So, I'm trying to test a hypothesis for a rank, nonparametric regression that  none of the measured variables contributed significantly to the determination of the total triglyceride level. So, my reduced model, r4, needs to only be the intercept. When I run the line for r4, it keeps giving me an error (I attached a screenshot of the error below). In my data, I have a column, INT, that has all 1's, so it isn't an issue with there not being a column for INT.

[image]

```
r4=rfit(totaltriglevel ~ INT,intercept=F,data=table9.11)
f1=rfit(totaltriglevel ~ sex + obese + chylomicrons + VLDL + LDL + HDL + Age, data=table9.11)
drop.test(f1,r4)
```

I have tried putting a 1 instead of INT, because I know with the lm function, that is how you get a intercept only model, but the rfit function doesn't like that, and I still haven't been able to find a solution. Can someone help me get on the right track?

Comment: I think the error tells you that you can't do what you want, i.e. you can't just have an intercept. I'd guess this is because these methods rely on the ranks of the response variable relative to the predictors.

Comment: @Limey I think that's what OP tried with their `INT` column. But neither `y ~ 1`, `y ~ INT`, `y ~ INT - 1` will work, all fail with the same error. It just checks whether the model matrix has any variance and will fail if not.

Comment: Can you not just use `summary(f1)` which reports an overall p-value for the model?